# Show tabPanel dynamically in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am using Shiny and I am trying to make a set of `tabPanels` appear dynamically based on a set of parameters. In the code below, I would like to make the first tabPanel appear only when `showTab1 <- T` and so on.

I tried with simple if statements and conditionalPanels but it fails. Below there is an example of code:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

showTab1 <- T
showTab2 <- F
showTab3 <- T


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(

  ),
  dashboardBody(
    uiOutput("tabs")
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) { 

output$tabs <- renderUI({


   tabBox(width = 1000,height = 500,

          if (showTab1 == T) { tabPanel("tab1") },

          if (showTab2 == T) { tabPanel("tab2") },

          if (showTab3 == T) { tabPanel("tab3") } 

          )



})


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks for your help.

Cheers,
Kostas

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Could have a look on the answer below?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for your answer earlier. Following your suggestion I think the following example can work for my case. The only issue I have is that in the end I cannot adjust the width and height of the `tabBox`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

showTab1 <- T
showTab2 <- F
showTab3 <- T

ShowTotal <- which(c(showTab1,showTab2,showTab3))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(uiOutput("ui"))
)
server <- function(input, output) { 

  output$ui <- renderUI({

    tabs <- list()
    k <- 0

    if (showTab1 == T){ 
        k <- k+1
        tabs[[k]] <- tabPanel("Tab1", p("A phrase"), br(""), p("I can place a chart here")) 
    }

    if (showTab2 == T){ 
        k <- k+1
    tabs[[k]] <- tabPanel("Tab2", p("B phrase"), br(""), p("I can place a chart here"))
    }

    if (showTab3 == T){ 
        k <- k+1
    tabs[[k]] <- tabPanel("Tab3", p("C phrase"), br(""), p("I can place a chart here"))
    }


    do.call(tabBox, tabs)

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks,
Kostas

Comment: this can be easily done by `do.call(tabBox, c(tabs, height = "200px"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically create them:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

showTab1 <- T
showTab2 <- F
showTab3 <- T

ShowTotal <- which(c(showTab1,showTab2,showTab3))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(uiOutput("ui"))
)
server <- function(input, output) { 

  output$ui <- renderUI({
    myTabs = lapply(paste('tab', ShowTotal), tabPanel)
    do.call(tabsetPanel, myTabs)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: if you see my previous response, I would like to work with tabBox instead of tabset panel. ok I understand that lapply  helps you avoid things but I have different if statements for each case and it is clearer.